# How to convert String into Integer in h:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I want to convert String into Integer in JSF hLselectOneMenu.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="rowsPerPage" value="#{AccountsController.rowsPerPage}" converter="javax.faces.Integer" maxlength="3">                                    
    <f:selectItem itemValue="10" itemLabel="10" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="50" itemLabel="50" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="100" itemLabel="100" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="500" itemLabel="500" />                                    
    <f:selectItem itemValue="094332" itemLabel="Custom" />
    <f:ajax render="customrowperpage" />
</h:selectOneMenu>&nbsp;
    <h:inputText id="customrowperpage" value="#{AccountsController.rowsPerPage}" rendered="#{AccountsController.rowsPerPage == '094332'}" required="true" />
```

How I can do this in JSF page?

P.S I updated the code but it the AJAX code is not working. When I select "custom" the input field is not rendered.

Answer (score 17):

Add the Integer converter via the converter attribute.

```
<h:selectOneMenu converter="javax.faces.Integer"/>
```

Comment: Note, that this doesn't work with PrimeFaces `<p:selectOneMenu>`. Aside from that, the component doesn't seem to require this at all. (just for those who google this up)

Comment: @Kawu Most of the time the component can detect the type of the bound _value_ without problems. There are cases where this won't work - For example usage of Generics: At compile time it is known there is an _Integer_ but in bytecode it is an _Object_. Here this solution helps!

Answer (score 5):

There are a few issues here.

- There is no attribute named `size` of the component `h:selectOneMenu`.  Remove this.
- The select item `custom` cannot be resolved to an integer, so as long as this select item exists you will get errors.
- You need to add a number converter to your `h:selectOneMenu` component.  `<f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" />`

Once you resolve these then there will be no problem binding the value of the component to a managed property that is an Integer type.

Comment: +1 for suggesting that there is no size attribute on h:selectOneMenu. I ran into this same issue converting a h:inputText to a h:selectOneMenu.